# Comparing XML date to holidays and weekends in XSLT while ignoring the time portion

Tags: xslt

I need to take a date from source xml, keep the date but zero out the time portion (I think).

My goal is to compare the input date to holidays and weekends so I can avoid them. The source date includes the time that it was submitted. Since I don't know what that time is going to be, I need to ignore it or zero it out so I can still compare the date to holidays and weekends.

Source XML

```
 <OrderRequestHeader orderID="3035" orderDate="2023-04-07T09:12:23" type="new">
</OrderRequestHeader>
```

XSLT to set holidays:

```
<xsl:variable name-"holidays" as="node()">
    <date>2023-05-29T00:00:00</date> <!--Memorial Day-->
    <date>2023-07-04T00:00:00</date> <!--Independence Day-->
    <date>2023-09-04T00:00:00</date> <!--Labor Day-->
    <date>2023-11-23T00:00:00</date> <!--Thanksgiving-->
    <date>2023-12-25T00:00:00</date> <!--Christmas-->
    <date>2024-01-01T00:00:00</date> <!--New Years Day-->
</xsl:variable>
```

I don't have the rest of the XSLT written yet, but I will be taking the orderDate, adding 3 days to it, then comparing it to the list of holidays, and adding an additional day if it lands on a holiday. What I can't figure out now is how to compare the orderDate with the holidays if the time's don't match.

thanks!

Comment: In all your questions regarding XSLT, please state which version of XSLT your processor supports.

Comment: First of all, unless you work with schema-aware XPath and/or XSLT, the attribute value of e.g. `orderDate` is only a string and not a dateTime, the same holds for your `date` element values. In any case, given an `xs:dateTime` value `$v`, you can just use `xs:date($v)` to get the date part.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I believe this method will return the date part along with the timezone part.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substring-before($yourDateTime, 'T')` to extract the date portion. Or, if your processor supports XSLT 2.0 or higher, you can subtract the time portion of `orderDate` to normalize all dateTimes to midnight.